# Varifocal glasses

Tags: optics, lenses

I hope this isn't the completely wrong community for my question, please let me know. I did search for 'varifocal' and got some hits, it seems (still getting used to these glasses, so it is a bit hard to use my PC)

So, it seems that when you get these glasses - we call them varifocal in UK, not sure if that is the international name? - they have these three zones with different strength, but for some reason, there are two blurry areas in the lower right and left corners. The top has the distance vision all across, but the computer- and reading strengths are only in the middle. I haven't been able to find an explanation online so far; does anybody here know of a good, technical reason for not simply providing three zones in the full width?

Comment: This is a very interesting question, and chances are someone here will know the answer. However, as it is currently written it is (almost) a question about engineering (as it is about the application of physics to a specific problem), and those are off-topic. I believe you can edit the question as to avoid that problem by asking for the physics constraints on varifocal lenses.

Comment: It might also be something you want to ask your optometrist, just in case they *aren't* supposed to be like that (only suffering mild myopia, I haven't any experience with bifocals, trifocals or other [progressive lenses](https://www.aao.org/eye-health/glasses-contacts/pros-cons-progressive-lenses-computer-glasses)).

Comment: It might just be that the middle of your visual field is the important part, so they didn't put much effort into the corners. It might be that you are looking through the corners at a steep angle instead of straight on. Spherical aberration is worse at the edge of a lens.

Comment: I think that you have a better chance of getting a good answer at [Medical Sciences Stack Exchange](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions)

Comment: They are called *progressive power lenses* of *PPL* for short. [Progressive Power Lenses](https://www.opticianonline.net/search?query=progressive) for a number of articles and the areas where the correction of astigmatism is very difficult are called *soft focus zones*. Pay more and the zones can be reduced in size and moved but never removed completely.